# Facebook video chat in ios sample

Tags: ios5, facebook-chat

I want  to integrate Facebook video chat in to my ios application.Please suggest me some sample, if no sample is available then please suggest how to integrate facebook video chat into ios application.

Thanks
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

I donno if you already found the answer. You may wanna check out this XMPP library for iOS.

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki